# Using the command line from within a Protractor test

Tags: integration-testing, protractor

I am trying to perform UI testing with Protractor. The application I am testing has a UI where updates happen in real time. These updates are driven by items being placed on a queue from another service. In order to test the updating of the screen I plan to write a small utility that will place items onto the queue to simulate the functionality under test. 
In order to do this in a controlled and testable manner I need to be able to trigger when an item is placed on the queue. Ideally I would trigger this during a test.

Is there a mechanism in Protractor where I can call a command line utility from inside a Protractor test, execute a batch file, or otherwise interact with an external application? If so could someone provide an example of such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is written in node js, so you can use any node js library. The library you should be interested is child_process. The document http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html contains a number of examples.